# How to use send email task in SSIS package?

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, ssis

I am New to SSIS,
So far I have configured the Database email using Basic Authentication in my SQL server management Studio.
Now I want to send an email from SSIS package.
I know that the send Email task only works with windows authentication.
I do not know What should I enter in SMTP server while I create the SMTP Connection manager.
I am working on my local system.
Can anyone please tell how can we configure the SMTP server and use it in Send mail task?
Any help is appreciated ?

Answer (score 1):

In your SSMS you can place the SEND MAIL TASK onto the design view of your *.dtsx package. Then double click the SMTP Connection Manager to input your email server creds (the server IP Address), and finally you can double click the Send Mail Task itself to fill out the email address and other information related to what you want to send.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply , Can you please tell in SMTP server you have entered the IP address 192.168.1.1 , Have you done any specific set-up/configuration on that server(192.168.1.1)?

Comment: That IP is simply an example to show you where you put the server IP address. Depending on what email server you use, your IP address should work if it's setup with SMTP, that's a separate issue from SSIS packages- in the example you are simply connecting to your email server and it will be used to hand off the email to be sent.

Comment: Can you please tell how can i configure my system with SMTP so that I can use it in send Mail task

Comment: you are using gmail to send email.. is that possible to use gmail in Send Email Task of SSIS? As per my understanding it is not possible.

Comment: @siddharthajain, it is not possible because gmail requires user/pwd authentication not supported by Send Mail Task. GabrielVa used that local IP as an example.